# Label isn't on the same line as its .input-group bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

```
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <label class="input-group-text form-floating ">Tell us Your Name *</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name">
   </div>
```

My code is like this, but what I want to do is to have the label part above the input part and be responsive. I will be glad if you help me

Comment: Im not sure what you are trying to do , you want to display the label for one of the input ??? (on the right or left part)

Comment: I wanted to make a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. It adds the row and col syntax in your html.

```
<div class="input-group mb-3 row">
  <label class="input-group-text form-floating col-12">Tell us Your Name *</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control col-6" placeholder="First Name">
  <input type="text" class="form-control col-6" placeholder="Last Name">
```

This will put the label at the top and the input fields below the label.

Comment: No problem if the answer satisfies your query please mark it as answered.

Comment: ı wan't to score  but ı new sorry

Comment: Haha, scoring wasn't an issue. I just wanted you to tick mark the answer so that other people know that the question has been answered. Anyways Happy to help!